# Ошибка Premission denied при работе с file_puts_contents

Tags: php, json

Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PHP Код:

```
$arr = array(
        $idv => [
            "vname" => $vname,
            "src" => $src,
            "desc" => $desc
        ]
    );
    $arr = json_encode($arr);
    file_put_contents("videos.json", $arr);
```

Comment: Призываю внутреннюю Вангу! Приди ко мне, о способность Видеть! Да, вот оно, вижу - у Вас отсутствует право на запись файла!

Comment: А как эту проблему решить?

Comment: Дать права на запись? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod